# Java with MyBatis postgreql postgis query - type geometry does not exist error

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, mybatis

I am running spring boot 2 and myBatis with postgresql.
I installed postgis extension in my db.
When running query from my app - I get error:

```
PSQLException: error: type "geometry" does not exist.
```

Running the same query in PGAdmin - I get the results, it means the extension installed successfully.
When running the query from Java without geometry param - also success.
This is the query from mybatis:

```
"<select id="selectMyFilters" parameterType="map" resultType="FilterOptions">
select ${column} as value,
from myFilters where 
${column} is not null 
<if test="geometry != null">
and (
<![CDATA]
ST_WITHIN (myGeo :: geometry, ST_SETSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${geometry}'),4326))
GROUP BY ${column};
</select>"
```

`MyGeo` column also has been defined in db as `GEOGRAPHY(POINTZ,4326)`

I spent on it 2 days already but cannot find the problem.

Anybody can help?

Comment: make sure the schema where postgis is installed (public by default) is in the user search path.

Comment: Yes, it is there, it successfully runs in pgAdmin

Comment: Make sure it is the same user, and that no code in your app reset the search path!

Comment: "Make sure it is the same user" - How can I do it?

Comment: check your app configuration! (i.e. maybe the app runs under "app_user" and you test in pgadmin under "slava")

Comment: I checked, the same user, it also successfully runs without geometry part of query from java app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to search path the public scheme, (in addition to the scheme that you fetch data from) because the gis is installed in the public scheme